# msi GE72 2QF Apache Pro, Windows 10 laptop

Tags: overwatch, monitor, framerate

I have a gamma issue. My computer is an msi GE72 2QF Apache Pro, Windows 10. It's a brand new computer, so the graphics card should be fine. The problem first started when I was playing Overwatch. I was playing regularly, but then suddenly the framerate started severely dropping at random times. I still haven't tested the framerate to see if it had anything to do with this problem, but I don't think it does. Pretty sure my computer was just overheating. I quit the game and went to the home page, and then suddenly the gamma (When I say gamma, I refer to brightness of the screen and brightness of the colors.) on my computer screen dramatically dropped.

I shut down Overwatch and went to my desktop, where the gamma had also decreased. I tried restarting my computer, and when I restarted it the gamma had gone back the the usual. I shut down a few programs, doing normal things, I launched Overwatch again, but then the gamma dropped back down to how it was earlier. I restarted AGAIN, and the same thing happened. I tried a final time, and everything was regular.

I tried launching Overwatch and the Battle.net launcher, but then again, the gamma went down. I closed Overwatch and Battle.net and my gamma was still low. I don't know how to fix this. Please help.

Comment: When you say gamma, are you referring to luminance, as in image/video display/encoding?

Comment: Try a different GPU intense game. Sounds like a Graphics card about to fail.

Comment: I don't think it's a failure of the graphics card, but it's more likely to be a driver issue and/or issue with some sort of "enhancement". (Like Nvida's game boost feature that will change the game's settings before startup for richer visuals or faster visuals).